# Как установить яндекс карту на фон слоя?

Tags: javascript, html, css, yandex-maps-api

Необходимо чтобы у определенного слоя или у всего сайта на фоне была яндекс карта.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот пример

http://jsfiddle.net/znf4pbbd/

```js
// Как только будет загружен API и готов DOM, выполняем инициализацию
        ymaps.ready(init);
 
        function init () {
            // Создание экземпляра карты и его привязка к контейнеру с
            // заданным id ("map")
            var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
                    // При инициализации карты, обязательно нужно указать
                    // ее центр и коэффициент масштабирования
                    center: [56.326944, 44.0075], // Нижний Новгород
                    zoom: 13
                });
        }
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
     height:100%
}
  body {
      height: 100%;
      margin:0px;
      padding:0px
}
  #map{
      height:100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
}

.content{
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.full&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="content">
        
</div>

<div id="map">
    
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Сразу заглянуть в документацию API я не догадался, а гугление ничего не дало) Сделал как в примере и всё работает!